# if string objects are interned then why change in one does not affect other

Tags: java

if string objects are interned then why change in one does not affect other

```
public class EqualExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = new String("Hello");
    String str1 = new String("Hello");

    System.out.println(str == str1);
    System.out.println(str1.equals(str));

}

}
```

Output of above programe would be

false
true

```
    public class EqualExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "Hello";
    String str1 = "Hello";

    System.out.println(str == str1);
    System.out.println(str1.equals(str));

}

}
```

Output of above code is

true
true

this is because in string pool Heloo alredy exists so it intern the string and refer to same object then why if i change str1 to "heloo java" then why str still have value "heloo". because they refer to same objects so the value of str must be change 
    public class EqualExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    String str = "Hello";
    String str1 = "Hello";

    System.out.println(str == str1);
    System.out.println(str1.equals(str));

    str1="Heloo java";
    System.out.println(str+str1);
    System.out.println(str == str1);
    System.out.println(str1.equals(str));

}

}
```

output true
true
HelooHeloo java
false
false

Comment: `String` objects are immutable. You cannot change the content of a `String` object.

Comment: Answer: Because strings are immutable, if you change value of the string it's the different string.

Answer (score 11):

`str1` is not a String. It is a reference to a String object. By doing

```
str1 = "Heloo java";
```

you're not modifying the String object, you're simply making the reference point to another, different String object.

Before:

```
str --------> "Hello"
                ^
str1 -----------|
```

After:

```
str --------> "Hello"

str1 -------> "Heloo Java"
```

Changing the object would consist in doing something like

```
str1.setCharacters("Heloo Java");
```

but such a method doesn't exist, because Strings are immutable. Their characters thus can't be modified (except by using dirty reflection tricks).

Answer (score 6):

You have two pointers pointing to the same address in memory. Changing one value means redirecting one pointer while the other one remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change an existing String. String is **immutable**. When you say 'changing `str1` to `"heloo java"`' you are in fact assigning a reference to a different immutable object.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html), `String`s are Immutable. That is: they don't change, or, once created: they never change (the state of the Object, not the reference variable.)

However, you can change the reference variable, creating a new `String` Object , in an existing reference variable. If there is no reference variable pointing to the "old" `String` Object, the "old" `String` Object is considered inaccessible by your program, and the Garbage Collector may clean it.

in practice, with comment explaining in the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String s1 = "Test 1";
    
    String s2 = s1;
    
    System.out.println("s1: "+s1+ " and s2: "+s2);
    
    s2 = "String 2";
    
    System.out.println("s1: "+s1+ " and s2: "+s2);
    
    //Garbage Collector will not clean the "String 1" because we still have the s1 Reference Variable pointing. 

}
```

OUTPUT:

> s1: Test 1 and s2: Test 1
>
> s1: Test 1 and s2: String 2

As you mentioned, to offer better performance, JVM don't create a new `String` object in the Heap if the new `String` created is "meaningfully equal" (pass in the `String.equals` method) to a existing one in the Heap. But you can force this creation by `new String("test 1")` in the reference variable.

**This Immutable state of `String` is to guarantee the good work of your program. Imagine how dangerous could be if you have two references of `String` and one of then changes: the other will be changed too and Strange Things could happen.**

Java Classes are Immutable too; like the Wrapper Classes: `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Double`, ....

I have illustrated the Garbage Collector to you deeply understand the Reference Variable relation with the Object in the Heap.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Hello"
```

Means

```
if "Hello" exists in the pool,
      then return "Hello" instance reference from pool
else
    create an object "Hello". Keep the object in the pool, then return reference
```

But

```
String str = new String("Hello");
```

means

Always create "Hello" object, irrespective of whether it exists in the pool or not.